# Google Site: API access to mature content is blocked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

> Service error: SitesApp: API access to mature content is blocked (line
>   21)

The above error message appears after I ran my Google app script. Is there any way to access Google sites with mature content enabled?

Comment: Please provide more information.  For example post the script your using.  It sounds like you have mature filtering enabled on your Google account.

Comment: Hi Ramhound,
Here my script
function myFunction() {
  var mySite=SitesApp.getSite('phimjav');
}
My google site: https://sites.google.com/site/phimjav/
If I enable mature content i will get error. Currently i disable it and my script run fine.

Sicay.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an undocumented restriction of the Google Sites API. We should include this in our documentation, and I see you have already filed [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1430) to track this.